# Add product with custom option to existing Order

Tags: magento

```
    $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($product)
            ->setQuote(Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId()));

        $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_quote')->itemToOrderItem($quoteItem)->setProduct($product);
```

this is the code i use to add a simple product to existing order , but i am having issues adding custom option product to the order.

```
$quoteItem->addOption(new Varien_Object(
                array(
                        'product' => $quoteItem->getProduct(),
                        'code' => 'option_ids',
                        'value' => 1 // 45,46,55
                     )
            ));

        $quoteItem->addOption(new Varien_Object(
                        array(
                            'product' => $quoteItem->getProduct(),
                            'code' => 'option_1',   //45
                            'value' => 2          // ‘White’
                         )
        ));
```

after the first line , but no success.

Any help please.

Thanks

Comment: I have similar problem here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/create-bundle-order-programmatically did you manage to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is one method to change exitsting order:
http://prattski.com/2013/04/22/magento-adding-items-to-existing-orders/